# Grouping graphql mutations

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to group my mutations into second level types.  The schema is parsed correctly, but resolvers aren't firing in Apollo.  Is this even possible?  Here's the query I want:

```
mutation {
    pets: {
        echo (txt:"test") 
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm trying to do it

Schema:

```
type PetsMutations {
    echo(txt: String): String
}

type Mutation {
    "Mutations related to pets"
    pets: PetsMutations
}

schema {
    mutation: Mutation
}
```

Resolvers:

```
  ...
  return {
    Mutation: {
      pets : {
        echo(root, args, context) {
            return args.txt;
        }
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `apollo-server` or `graphql-tools`, you cannot nest resolvers in your resolver map like that. Each property in the resolver map should correspond to a type in your schema, and itself be a map of field names to resolver functions. Try something like this:

```
{
  Mutation: {
    // must return an object, if you return null the other resolvers won't fire
    pets: () => ({}),
  },
  PetsMutations: {
    echo: (obj, args, ctx) => args.txt,
  },
}
```

Side note, your query isn't valid. Since the `echo` field is a scalar, you can't have a subselection of fields for it. You need to remove the empty brackets.

Comment: Thanks!  Updated the query in the question to be valid.